# What is the track that plays at 19:41 of One Piece Episode 84?

Tags: one-piece, music

Heard it and it sounded amazing but haven’t been able to find it.
 Episode 84 of One Piece, starting at 19:41.

Comment: Can you include when in the video it plays (approximately)? Right now we can't tell without watching the whole episode.

Answer (score 1):

### You can listen here: [OnePieceTrackList](http://onepiecetracklist.com/Music/16.mp3)

Starting from 1:31 on the track, the track is named "Anger!!" from "Music & Song Collection 1", track #11. The track starts at 19:41 on the soundtrack.

Comment: I wasn't able to find a youtube video of this song (sorry about that) so you'll have to use the link provided ;)